# What is the idiomatic way to shift and extend a list by a number of elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, coding-style

I have a lists, `list`, and want shift it right by a given number of elements, `m`, extending the list by repeating the last element. A form that works is

```
Drop[#, m]& @ PadRight[#, Length[#] + m, Last[#]]& @ list
```

which, for

```
m = 3
list = {3, 0, 7, 2, 1}
```

gives

```
{2, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

and for

```
m = 2
list = {3, 8, 2, 7, 1, 6}
```

gives

```
{2, 7, 1, 6, 6, 6}
```

This is what I want, but I wonder if there is a more idiomatic way to accomplish it.

Comment: Perhaps the accepted terminology is different among *Mathematica* users, but don't you mean you're shifting the list to the *left*?

Comment: @DavidZhang: Yes, indeed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I may be back to using *gedanken Mathematica*, but I'm confident this works:

```
m = 2;
ArrayPad[{3, 8, 2, 7, 1, 6}, {-m, m}, "Fixed"]
   {2, 7, 1, 6, 6, 6}
```

Comment: Cool. I knew there had to be something.

Answer (score 4):

ArrayPad does precisely what you want, nevertheless I'd suggest one more solution without calling a special function, which I think a little clearer than the original with Drop and PadRight:

```
Join[list[[m + 1 ;;]], Table[list[[-1]], {m}]]
```